# Magento 2 : Class Magento\ServicesConnector\Api\ConfigInterface does not exist

Tags: magento2.3, setup-di-compile

When I'm setting up the Magento system, facing error as

> Class `Magento\ServicesConnector\Api\ConfigInterface` does not exist
>   during

`setup:di:compile`

Does anyone have Magento_ServicesConnector module?

Using Magento 2.3 open source edition.

Comment: forgot to add `composer require magento/services-connector:~1.0.3`  in the `composer.json`.. it solved now. service connector is a mandatory module for amazon module.  (https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/amazon-sales)

Comment: Can provide all steps to install amazon-sales module?

Comment: I followed this guide - https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/amazon-sales/#install

Comment: run composer require magento/services-connector:~1.0.3 but got this error
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
    - magento/module-services-id 2.2.2 requires magento/services-connector ~1.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/services-connector[1.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: which is correct magento/amazon-sales-channel  or magento/module-amazon

Comment: Can you tell what is amazon module version and service connector version?